# Set parameter within a step of a Pipeline (XGB : eval_set)

Tags: python, pipeline

I am trying to fit an XGBoost model to my data with an early stopping round and therefore an eval_set parameter. However, I am using a pipeline that does preprocessing before the model fitting step. I would want to set the parameter "eval_set" to that particular step and have used the syntax "stepname__eval_set=.." which doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code :

```
XGB=XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10000,learning_rate=0.05,verbose=False)
myPip=Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessing",preprocessor),
                     ("model",XGB)])
myPip.fit(X_train2,y_train,model__eval_set=[(X_val2,y_val)],model__early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

It returns the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\PCGZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17976/459508294.py in <module>
      2 myPip=Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessing",preprocessor),
      3                      ("model",XGB)])
----> 4 myPip.fit(X_train2,y_train,model__eval_set=[(X_val2,y_val)],model__early_stopping_rounds=5)
      5 y_pred_val=myPip.predict(X_val2)
      6 y_pred_train=myPip.predict(X_train2)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    344             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    345                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 346                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    347 
    348         return self

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    618             for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    619                 kwargs[k] = arg
--> 620             return func(**kwargs)
    621 
    622         return inner_f

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
   1012         with config_context(verbosity=self.verbosity):
   1013             evals_result: TrainingCallback.EvalsLog = {}
-> 1014             train_dmatrix, evals = _wrap_evaluation_matrices(
   1015                 missing=self.missing,
   1016                 X=X,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in _wrap_evaluation_matrices(missing, X, y, group, qid, sample_weight, base_margin, feature_weights, eval_set, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, eval_group, eval_qid, create_dmatrix, enable_categorical, feature_types)
    497                 evals.append(train_dmatrix)
    498             else:
--> 499                 m = create_dmatrix(
    500                     data=valid_X,
    501                     label=valid_y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in _create_dmatrix(self, ref, **kwargs)
    932             except TypeError:  # `QuantileDMatrix` supports lesser types than DMatrix
    933                 pass
--> 934         return DMatrix(**kwargs, nthread=self.n_jobs)
    935 
    936     def _set_evaluation_result(self, evals_result: TrainingCallback.EvalsLog) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    618             for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    619                 kwargs[k] = arg
--> 620             return func(**kwargs)
    621 
    622         return inner_f

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in __init__(self, data, label, weight, base_margin, missing, silent, feature_names, feature_types, nthread, group, qid, label_lower_bound, label_upper_bound, feature_weights, enable_categorical)
    741             return
    742 
--> 743         handle, feature_names, feature_types = dispatch_data_backend(
    744             data,
    745             missing=self.missing,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in dispatch_data_backend(data, missing, threads, feature_names, feature_types, enable_categorical)
    955         return _from_tuple(data, missing, threads, feature_names, feature_types)
    956     if _is_pandas_df(data):
--> 957         return _from_pandas_df(data, enable_categorical, missing, threads,
    958                                feature_names, feature_types)
    959     if _is_pandas_series(data):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in _from_pandas_df(data, enable_categorical, missing, nthread, feature_names, feature_types)
    402     feature_types: Optional[FeatureTypes],
    403 ) -> DispatchedDataBackendReturnType:
--> 404     data, feature_names, feature_types = _transform_pandas_df(
    405         data, enable_categorical, feature_names, feature_types
    406     )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in _transform_pandas_df(data, enable_categorical, feature_names, feature_types, meta, meta_type)
    376         for dtype in data.dtypes
    377     ):
--> 378         _invalid_dataframe_dtype(data)
    379 
    380     feature_names, feature_types = _pandas_feature_info(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py in _invalid_dataframe_dtype(data)
    268     type_err = "DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category."
    269     msg = f"""{type_err} {_ENABLE_CAT_ERR} {err}"""
--> 270     raise ValueError(msg)
    271 
    272 

ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category. When categorical type is supplied, The experimental DMatrix parameter`enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.  Invalid columns:MSZoning: object, Street: object, LotShape: object, LandContour: object, Utilities: object, LotConfig: object, LandSlope: object, Neighborhood: object, Condition1: object, Condition2: object, BldgType: object, HouseStyle: object, RoofStyle: object, RoofMatl: object, Exterior1st: object, Exterior2nd: object, MasVnrType: object, ExterQual: object, ExterCond: object, Foundation: object, BsmtQual: object, BsmtCond: object, BsmtExposure: object, BsmtFinType1: object, BsmtFinType2: object, Heating: object, HeatingQC: object, CentralAir: object, Electrical: object, KitchenQual: object, Functional: object, GarageType: object, GarageFinish: object, GarageQual: object, GarageCond: object, PavedDrive: object, SaleType: object, SaleCondition: object
```

PS : The prepocessing pipeline isn't the issue, since the pipeline worked fine with other models that do not take the eval_set parameter.

Thank you in advance for your kindly help.

Comment: What aspect of the diagnostic do you find unclear? There's quite a few `object` columns mixed in there, and they won't work with your current setup.

Comment: I must have misunderstood how pipelines worked, I initially thought the pipeline would preprocess the evalutation set and therefore avoiding that particular problem. I'll try to work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found "a" solution for this particular problem : which was passing the eval_set parameter (which was unprocessed data) to the model that was fitted using preprocessed data. Trying to evaluate it with unprocessed data that ultimately had a different column structure gave the error shown above.
The idea is to perform the pipeline step by step, just like so :

```
XGB=XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10000,learning_rate=0.05,verbose=False)
#This is our original Pipeline
myPip=Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessing",preprocessor),
                     ("model",XGB)])
#We fit the preprocessing step on the unprocessed training data
myPip[0].fit(X_train2,y_train)
#And transform both the training and validation data
X_trainXGB=myPip[0].transform(X_train2)
X_valXGB=myPip[0].transform(X_val2)
#We fit the model on the clean data
myPip[1].fit(X_trainXGB,y_train,eval_set=[(X_valXGB,y_val)],early_stopping_rounds=5)
#And predict the result using the preprocessed (transformed) validation data
y_preds=myPip[1].predict(X_valXGB)
```